# Making a string into a single digit DF column using R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have long inputs that i've imported with readChar which look like this "[1] "1100?001?01??110?10?????101011?111????11?1?1????????1??01?101??01?????1??????1??111??0?1?11?1110?".

I want to separate each string by digit:
"1, 1, 0, 0, ?, 0, 0, 1..."
and turn each of these lists into columns of a dataframe so that I can compare input strings easily.

I've tried separating the digits using strsplit() but because they aren't comma separated I can't seem to do much with them.

I've tried turning the strsplit output into a list. This added the whole string to every row of my dataframe instead of separate digits in order on each row.

I can't figure this out. Please help.

Comment: You can use `read.fwf` i.e. `read.fwf(textConnection(str1), widths = rep(1, max(nchar(str1))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this adds one character per row:

```r
library(tidyverse)

as_tibble_col(unlist(str_split("1100?001?01??110?10?????101011?111????11?1?1????????1??01?101??01?????1??????1??111??0?1?11?1110?", "")), "col1")

# # A tibble: 97 × 1
#    col1 
#    <chr>
#  1 1    
#  2 1    
#  3 0    
#  4 0    
#  5 ?    
#  6 0    
#  7 0    
#  8 1    
#  9 ?    
# 10 0    
# # … with 87 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we add a space after each character to better separate the rows within as_tibble:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x <- "1100?001?01??110?10?????101011?111????11?1?1????????1??01?101??01?????1??????1??111??0?1?11?1110?"
y <- sub("\\s+$", "", gsub('(.{1})', '\\1 ', x))

y %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  separate_rows("value")
```

```
   value
   <chr>
 1 1    
 2 1    
 3 0    
 4 0    
 5 0    
 6 0    
 7 1    
 8 0    
 9 1    
10 1    
# ... with 39 more rows
```